# BSOD after running Virtual Router

Tags: windows-7, router, bsod

I have downloaded and installed Virtual Router Manager 0.9 under Windows 7 from virtualrouter.codeplex.com. It is great. But while running, a blue screen of death suddenly appears randomly every time I run it. Attached link below is the picture of the BSOD I receive.

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2njk8qh.jpg]

Anyone who knows the proper action for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the BOSD, bcmw16.sys appears to be part of your wireless or ethernet adapter drivers so I would suggest updating those first.

If that doesn't help I would suggest asking on the [discussion forum on virtualrouter.codeplex.com](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/discussions) as well as on here as the software seems to be the cause of the problem as well.